# How to read the modified setting defined in my own sbt plugin

Tags: sbt

I tried to create my own sbt plugin by following this [guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html), and had the following code:

`build.sbt` in myplugin

```
sbtPlugin := true

lazy val plugin = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "myplugin",
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
  )
```

`HelloPlugin.scala` in myplugin

```
package sbthello

import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    val greeting = settingKey[String]("greeting")
    val obfuscate = taskKey[String]("Obfuscates files.")
  }
  import autoImport._
  lazy val baseSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    greeting := "Hi!",
    obfuscate := {
      println(greeting.value)
      greeting.value + " value"
    }
  )

  override val projectSettings =
    inConfig(Compile)(baseSettings)
}
```

the `build.sbt` in test project is

```
lazy val usage = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(HelloPlugin).
  settings(
    name := "sbt-test",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4")
  .settings(
    greeting := "Hello"
  )
```

with the files above, the execution result is:

```
> show obfuscate
Hi!
[info] Hi! value
> show greeting
[info] Hello
```

the obfuscate task cannot read the "Hello" value

if modify `greeting := "Hi!"` in `HelloPlugin.scala` to `greeting in obfuscate := "Hi!",`

the obfuscate task can read the "Hello" value now

```
> show greeting
[info] Hello
> show obfuscate
Hello
[info] Hello value
```

but now I cannot remove `greeting := "Hello"` in buildInDemo.sbt, or else it will have such errors:

```
[error] References to undefined settings:
[error]
[error]   compile:greeting from compile:obfuscate ((sbthello.HelloPlugin) HelloPlugin.scala:40)
[error]      Did you mean compile:obfuscate::greeting ?
[error]
[error]   compile:greeting from compile:obfuscate ((sbthello.HelloPlugin) HelloPlugin.scala:40)
[error]      Did you mean compile:obfuscate::greeting ?
[error]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### configuration scoping

```scala
override val projectSettings =
  inConfig(Compile)(baseSettings)
```

This scopes all the settings in `baseSettings` into `Compile` configuration. So it's the same as saying:

1. Define `greeting in Compile` setting.
2. Refer to the `greeting in Compile` setting from `obfuscate in Compile` task.

So in `build.sbt` you should customize as

```scala
greeting in Compile := "Hello"
```

You can access this setting from the shell as:

```
> compile:greeting
```

If you don't want the behavior, don't put `baseSettings` in `inConfig(...)`.

### task and configuration scoping

`greeting in obfuscate` is task scoping. So combined with `inConfig(...)` that'll require

```scala
greeting in (Compile, obfuscate) := "Hello"
```

to customize.

For more details see [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html).

Comment: thanks a lot,Eugene. What I should do is to change "override val projectSettings = inConfig(Compile)(baseSettings)" to "override val projectSettings = baseSettings".